# how to send form values using spring form?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

In my login.jsp have the following code..

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<fieldset id="signin_menu">
    <form:form action="login/processLogin" modelAttribute="LOGIN">
        -----
    </form:form>
</fieldset>
```

And my LoginForm have userName,password and setters and getters..
When ever click the Submit Button Form values coming ...

But when we click `Forgot Password?` link Form values not coming hear null values coming..

Comment: Does `$('#LOGIN').ajaxForm` getting executed on both situations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a form submision to get the form values

```
$('.submit_forgotPassword').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this).parents('form');
    frm.attr('action', 'login/forgotPassword');
    frm.submit();
});
```